# Problems with syntax c++

Tags: c++

I'm having problems with: (all line 34)

1. expected unqualified-id before "for"
2. expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '!=' token
3. expected `,' or`;' before "for"
4. `i' was not declared in this scope

And i can't seem to find a solution, i've looked for sintax errors, but it seems fine to me.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int arg[], int length)
{
    char c [3];
    char r [5];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    cout << "Inserisci i numeri delle colonne: (3 numeri) ";
    cin >> c[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    cout << "Inserisci i numeri delle righe: (5 numeri) ";
    cin >> r[i];
    }
    ofstream fout("DatiArray.txt");
    if(fout.is_open())
    {
    cout << "File aperto con successo!\n";
    }
    i=0;
     for(i=0; c[i] !='\0'; i++)
       {
       fout << c[i];
       } 
        cout << "Dati delle colonne scritti nel file DatiArray.txt con successo!\n";
        }

         for ( i=0; r[i] !='\0'; i++)  // this line 
        {
        fout << r[i];
        }
         cout << "Dati delle righe scritti nel file DatiArray.txt con successo!\n";
         }

 system ("PAUSE");    
}
```

Comment: It might help to indent your code properly.

Comment: [_This_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232) might be useful

Comment: Most modern text-editors have parentheses and brace matching, and most also have automatic indentation, use those tools.

Comment: .. and then learn how to indent code manually, anyway. It's not difficult.

Comment: Also, in the future please copy-paste the *actual* error log, unedited and complete. And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think you have 6 `{` and 8 `}`. You have 2 extra `}` after last two `cout`'s

Comment: first arg of `'main'` must be of type 'int'

Comment: BTW, that is not one of the standard signatures for `main`...

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
 for(i=0; c[i] !='\0'; i++)
       {
       fout << c[i];
       } 
        cout << "Dati delle colonne scritti nel file DatiArray.txt con successo!\n";
        }
```

you have one closing bracket too many.

Answer (score 1):

You have an excess `}` (and, again, later on in your program).

This would have been very easy to spot if you used any sort of rational code indentation scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is outside of your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others pointed out, below are my observations.

```
char c [3];
for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
```

You are filling up the array till last element. And then,

```
 for(i=0; c[i] !='\0'; i++)
```

you are running loop to find null character which you not inserted as there was no space left for that charcter.

Comment: True but not the problem...

Comment: Did I say that? No. I said you are right, but that this is not the problem being asked about.

Comment: Well, I would say I didn't read question properly then...:)